# Why am I getting this error: imutils VideoStream(src=0) return VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument in raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, webcam, imutils

I am only running this simple code in my Raspberry Pi 4:

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream

# initialize the video streams and allow them to warmup
print("[INFO] starting cameras...")
webcam = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

I can run this code without any problem with the Raspberry Pi camera, but I get error with my Logitech C310 webcam.

The error is: `VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument`

The camera works perfectly when used with `fswebcam` in the terminal. I also tried using it with online webcam test, and it works. My only problem is the camera can't be used with my Python code. I also tried using it with opencv and it returned `None`.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4 4GB

OS: Raspbian Buster

Hope anyone can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with a Logitech C920 by lowering the resolution. At the maximum resolution (1920x1080) I also get the `VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument` error, however by lowering the resolution I am able to read the frames:

```
from cv2 import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Change the camera setting using the set() function
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)

retval, frame = cam.read()

# do stuff with the captured image here
cam.release()
```